# How do i delete rows from data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, rows, delete-row, drop

This is aggregation to the column from the data frame:

```
Material_Type   
ZHW1        155437.557652
ZHW3        12432.078625
ZUB1        487.222162
```

And I want to delete the `ZUB1` category.

I tried:

```
 df.loc[(df!='ZUB1').any(1)]
```

and Im stiil geting the same count of rows from the original data frame.
tnx in advance.

Comment: Use `df[df.Material_Type!='ZUB1']` if `Material_Type` is column

Comment: @jezrael tnx!!!